# In admin-on-rest, how to change the Chrome Tab title from "React App"

Tags: admin-on-rest

When I have admin-on-rest app running, the client Chrome Tab always shows "React App" instead of whatever title I set in Admin component in App.js. Is there way to customize the tile of the tab to something else?

[React App screenshot shown in Chrome Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq4pZ.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-new-reactjs-app.html

It's a matter of changing index.html

Open up public/index.html and edit the title tag to the following:

Scratch - A simple note taking app

Comment: I'd like to piggy-back off of @gliu_me answers and add that you can use `react-helmet` to further manipulate head's data. Read more at https://alligator.io/react/react-helmet/